# ElasticSearch sort exception - might be NEST related

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

We recently upgraded from ES 0.23 to 0.90 and now my queries, eg:

```
{
  "sort": {
    "companyname.sort": {
      "order": "asc"
    }
  }
}
```

cause an exception:

```
{
error: SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[Y8U7j2f-QvS75-6SfxlGuA][boss][0]:

QueryPhaseExecutionException[[boss][0]:
query[ConstantScore(cache(_type:SalesCompany))],from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:"companyname.sort":
org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.BytesRefFieldComparatorSource@292f8639>]: 
Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException; }{[Y8U7j2f-QvS75-6SfxlGuA][boss][1]: QueryPhaseExecutionException[[boss][1]:
query[ConstantScore(cache(_type:SalesCompany))],from[0],size[10],sort[<custom:"companyname.sort": 
org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.fieldcomparator.BytesRefFieldComparatorSource@292f8639>]: Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: NullPointerException; }]
status: 500
}
```

If I run the same query on our staging environment with an index that was created with 0.23 - but has ES 0.90 installed - it works fine.  The mapping is:

```
companyname: {
    type: multi_field
    fields: {
        companyname: {
            type: string
            store: true
            analyzer: simple
        }
        sort: {
            type: string
            index: not_analyzed
            store: true
            omit_norms: true
            index_options: docs
            analyzer: simple
            include_in_all: false
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the latest version of NEST from a .Net C# app to create the index and query it.

I havent yet tried to recreate the index on the staging environment as I don't want to break that until I know how to fix it :)

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: After much digging I think this is a know issue that has been fixed: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3477

Answer (score 0):

I have recently switched to ES 0.90.7 and latest Nest.  All is now well in the world.